# Setting scope to "public" does not restrict private videos (Vimeo API)

Tags: api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using Vimeo API, and the authorisation URL is

```
https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=****&scope=public&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=****&state=****
```

As you can see I have set the scope to "public", however on authentication window I see this

[image: Vimeo Authorization Window]

Both the Public and Private permission comes up, and I can not uncheck any of them.

Also as a follow up question, I have set `approval_prompt = auto` but still the authorization window comes up every time even if I have allowed permissions before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time that you tried this Vimeo required that you always have both the private and public scopes. At that same time, Vimeo was working on removing that restriction.

Yesterday Vimeo launched that change, and you should be able to create an access token that only has the "public" scope. If you are still having problems, let me know and we can dig into it further.

Comment: Yes it is fine now.

Comment: Also, I have set approval_prompt = auto but still the authorization window comes up every time even if I have allowed permissions before.

Comment: Vimeo does not support the approval_prompt flag.

Comment: so is there any way to achieve the above thing?

Comment: You can get an access token, and store it in your db for future use, but you can't skip the approval screen.